# Blackberry application not working in wifi

Tags: blackberry, wifi

hi all i have made application for blackberry .it is working on my Blackberry 8310 device  .i m using vodafone Blackberry dataservice in 8310 and app working fine .but when i install this app in my 9550 and i want to used this app using wifi but i app not working using wifi so what is the reason for that. ? therer is any extra setting for wifi ?

Comment: How are you connecting when there is Wi-Fi available?

Comment: i havent add any exta code for getting wifi .how can we handle it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it looks like you haven't heard about network transports. If this is the case, then it's a miracle your app worked OK on the first device! :)

Network transports is a BB specific concept. Check [Connecting your BlackBerry - http and socket connections to the world](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Connecting-your-BlackBerry-http-and-socket-connections-to-the/m-p/206243). Basically you end up with a url that is appended with a specific string that tells to the BB internals what network transport to use.

Comment: Thanx arhimed realy this is very helpful document to understand how we can understand BB network connection. but i m using OS 5.0 device with wifi so still dont get any result for wifi .its argent please any idea for wifi help me .

Comment: Have you setup WiFi on the device? Can you check it works for some other app on your device? Also without seeing the code it's difficult to say what's wrong.

Comment: i have downloaded other application from BB market but it also not working . i used internet through BB browser through wifi connection.

Comment: Also, check this BB doc "What Is - Network API alternative for legacy OS" - http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/What-Is-Network-API-alternative-for-legacy-OS/ta-p/614822 . There is a handy tool for your case - Network Diagnostic Tool, which can be used to quickly test specific transports with a given URL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
HttpConnection httpConnector = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url + ";interface=wifi");
```

Comment: Thanx this is working in device 4.5 but still have problem in os 5.0 using wifi